# MongoDB - Math calculations

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need to calculate this `((86400 + (7200 - 28800)) % 86400)` in MongoDB's aggregate. Is it possible? Or need to do this on JavaScript.
Is mongo support remainder of division?

Comment: [mod](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/mod/) will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, quite possible. The [arithmetic operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#arithmetic-operators) provide mathematic operations on numbers. The remainder is supported with the **[`$mod`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mod/#exp._S_mod)** operator. The desired calculation can be done using the expression, for example:

```
pipeline = [
    {
        "$project": {
            "result": {
                "$mod": [
                    {
                        "$add": [
                            86400,
                            { "$subtract": [7200, 28800] }
                        ]
                    },
                    86400
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Executing this aggregate pipeline on a collection will yield:

```
db.collection.aggregate(pipeline)
```

**Sample Output**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58aacd498caf670a837e7093"),
    "result" : 64800
}
```